# Как сохранить информацию input-а после перезагрузки страницы

Tags: javascript, html, input, localstorage

Сделал страницу где есть `input`-ы `type:` `text`, `file` `radio`, а также выпадающий список `select`. Хочу чтобы при перезагрузке страницы информация сохранялась. Я использую такой код `javascript` для сохранения информации:

```
if (window.localStorage) {
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll('[name]');

  for (var i = 0, length = elements.length; i < length; i++) {
    (function (element) {
      var name = element.getAttribute('name');

      element.value = localStorage.getItem(name) || '';

      element.onkeyup = function () {
        localStorage.setItem(name, element.value);
      };
    })(elements[i]);
  }
}
```

Если тексты в `input type text` сохраняются, то выбранные опции `select, radio, file` нет. Как можно дополнить этот код чтобы сохранялись и остальные?
Код на `html`:

```
<div class="file">
      <input type="file" id="file" class="myfile" name="file" />
    </div>

  <div class="brands">
      <select id="brand" class="brand">
        <option value="1">HP</option>
        <option value="2">Dell</option>
        <option value="3">Microsoft</option>
        <option value="4">Apple</option>
        <option value="5">Lenovo</option>
        <option value="6">Acer</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <input
        type="radio"
        id="SSD"
        name="memory_type"
        value="1"
        selected="selected"
      /><label for="SSD">SSD</label>
      <input type="radio" id="HDD" name="memory_type" value="2" /><label
        for="HDD"
        >HDD</label
      >
    </div>
```

Comment: Насчёт `file` посложнее будет, а остальные, не "текстовые", используют не `value`: radio, checkbox - `input.checked`, select - `select.options[select.selectedIndex]` (получит выбранный `option`).

Comment: хорошо, спасибо